# Flutter Freezed/json_serializable - runtimeType is missing from generated json

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, json-serializable, flutter-freezed

For some reason the `runtimeType` is missing in the generated json of this Freezed class. It only happens sometimes. See image below:

[image]

This causes the switch case in the image to fall through to `throw FallThroughError();`, since `runtimeType` doesn't exist.

Here is the class:

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/application/entities/option/option.dart';
import '../vegan_item.dart';

part 'basic_vegan_item.freezed.dart';
part 'basic_vegan_item.g.dart';

@freezed
class BasicVeganItem extends VeganItem with _$BasicVeganItem {
  const factory BasicVeganItem(
      {int? id,
      String? name,
      String? companyName,
      String? imageBucketName,
      String? description,
      String? image,
      List<Option>? tags,
      @Default(0) int isNotVeganCount,
      @Default(0) int isVeganCount,
      int? rating,
      @Default(0) int ratingsCount,
      @Default(1) int currentRevisionId}) = _BasicVeganItem;

  const factory BasicVeganItem.groceryItem(
      {int? id,
      String? name,
      String? companyName,
      @Default('vp-grocery-items') String? imageBucketName,
      String? description,
      String? image,
      List<Option>? tags,
      @Default(0) int isNotVeganCount,
      @Default(0) int isVeganCount,
      int? rating,
      @Default(0) int ratingsCount,
      @Default(1) int currentRevisionId}) = GroceryItem;

  const factory BasicVeganItem.menuItem(
      {int? id,
      String? name,
      String? companyName,
      @Default('vp-menu-items') String? imageBucketName,
      String? description,
      String? image,
      List<Option>? tags,
      @Default(0) int isNotVeganCount,
      @Default(0) int isVeganCount,
      int? rating,
      @Default(0) int ratingsCount,
      @Default(1) int currentRevisionId}) = MenuItem;

  const BasicVeganItem._();

  factory BasicVeganItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$BasicVeganItemFromJson(json);
}
```